Using bootstrap to estimate covariance of mean estimators from two distinct (dependant) populations
Given two samples : an i.i.d. $n_u$-sample $(u_{j})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}$ and an i.i.d. $n_v$-sample $(v_{i})_{1 \leq i \leq n_v}$.
Note : The populations of the two samples are disjoint (let's say we choose the prices of bananas for $u$ and the prices of oranges for $v$). These samples are not necessarily drawn independently in the sense that the draw of some units $u_i$ can be linked with the draw of some units $v_j$ (maybe we chose some bananas and oranges in the same market).
We can create an estimator of the means of these two samples, respectively $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{v}$.
My goal here is to estimate the covariance of $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{v}$ if it is possible (I suppose that the non-indenpendancy of the draws of the two samples can cause the covariance to be non-zero, and I want to estimate this covariance).
My idea
So my idea is to create bootstrap re-samples of $(u_{j})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}$ and $(v_{i})_{1 \leq i \leq n_v}$ we could write $\left\{ (u_{j}^{*(b)})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}, (v_{i}^{*(b)}))_{1 \leq i \leq n_v} \right\}_{b=1}^B$.
And with that we can have the means $u^{*(b)}=\frac{1}{n_u - 1} \sum_{j \in b} u_{j}^{*(b)}$ and the same goes for $v^{*(b)}$.
Thus, I think an estimator of $\text{Cov}(\bar{u}_{n_u},\bar{v}_{n_v})$ can be :
$$
\frac{1}{B-1} \sum_{b=1}^B (u^{*(b)} - \bar{u}^{*})(v^{*(b)} - \bar{v}^{*}).
$$
However I fail to prove that this estimator truly estimates the covariance. I wrote that if we consider the conditional expectation (I write $\mathbb{E}^*\left[ . \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ .|(u_{j})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}, (v_{i})_{1 \leq i \leq n_u}\right]$) :
$$
\mathbb{E}^*\left[ (u^{*(b)} - \bar{u}^{*})(v^{*(b)} - \bar{v}^{*})\right] = \frac{1}{(n_u - 1)(n_v - 1)} \sum_{i \in b}\sum_{j \in b} \mathbb{E}^*\left[ (u_{j}^{*(b)} - \bar{u}^{*})(v_{j}^{*(b)} - \bar{v}^{*})\right]
$$
And then,
$$
\mathbb{E}^*\left[ (u_{j}^{*(b)} - \bar{u}^{*})(v_{j}^{*(b)} - \bar{v}^{*})\right] = \text{Cov}^*(u_{j}^{*(b)}, v_{j}^{*(b)}) - \mathbb{E}^*(\bar{u}^{*})\mathbb{E}^*(\bar{v}^{*})
$$
By the law of the unconscious statistician,
$$\mathbb{E}^*(\bar{u}^{*}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n_u} \mathbb{P}(u_{i}^{*(b)}= u_{k}|(u_{j})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u})\times u_{k} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n_u} \frac{1}{n_u} u_{k} = \bar{u}_{n_u}$$
So $\mathbb{E}^*(\bar{u}^{*})\mathbb{E}^*(\bar{v}^{*}) = \bar{u}_{n_u}\bar{u}_{n_v}$.
However I can't resist to say that $\text{Cov}^*(u_{j}^{*(b)}, v_{j}^{*(b)})=0$ because the draw on the $u_i$ and the draw of the $v_j$ are independant in our bootstrap re-samples.
I want to say first that I am not really confident with the use of bootstrap methods. I think that this is due to the fact we draw independantly our two re-samples in the bootstrap when the two samples are not drawn independantly from the population, however how to make sure our re-sample draw can be as if it was the one from the samples ? Maybe, it is just impossible to do so.
Thanks in advance for your replies !
